# Add background image while remain RelativeLayout

Tags: android

This is my *activity_login.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/userid"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_login" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_register" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="@string/newuser" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want **pos_malaysia.png** to be set as my login page background on the top center on the screen.. I saw some of them say use `<bitmap>` .

The thing is when I replace `RelativeLayout` with `bitmap` all the `android:layout_above="@+id/userid"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` cannot be used since its only applies for RelativeLayout. what should I do to maintain the layout with added background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions for it.

**1st** add **android:background="@drawable/[PIC]"** to your Relative Layout.

**2nd** add **ImageView** as 1st layer (on bottom) of Relative Layout.

Depends on what kind of background (logo, image) you should consider using 9patch, so it will nicely scale.

Comment: Ok got it~ just can teach me about bitmap? or maybe a link to it?

Comment: as background you can use a drawable located in your resources/drawable folder, or load it from your assets directory (Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("Cloths/btn_no.png"), null);)

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to add background use

> android:background="@drawable/image_name"

(provided that the image you are planning to load is in the Project resources.)

in widget or RelativeLayout
if you would like to maintain its size create syle or just create imageView

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can same in linear layout as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
tools:ignore="ExtraText"
android:background="@drwable/your_bg_image"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/userid"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_login" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_register" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="@string/newuser" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:useDefaultMargins="true"
 tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/*****YOUR IMAGE NAME****"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```